# Series of complex functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I don't understand how to solve exercises like this, and I couldn't find anything useful neither on my book (Stein Shakarchi) nor on the internet:

> Show that the function $$f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}(2z)^{-n^2}$$ is holomorphic in $\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|\gt\frac 1 2\}.$ Then calculate $$\int_{C_1(0)}z^kf(z)dz$$ for every non negative integer $k$.

I'm stuck with the first part: I know that a succession of holomorphic functions converges to a holomorphic function, but I don't think I must apply this fact to the partial sums of the series.
I don't think that power series are involved neither; can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\sum (\frac z 2)^{n^{2}}$ By root test this series is convergent for $|z| <2$. Call the sum $g$. Then $g$ is holomorphic in $\{z:|z| <2\}$ and $f(z)=g(\frac 1 z)$. Hence $f$ holomorphic in $\{z:|z| >\frac 1 2\}$.

Hint for second part: you only have to find $\int_{C_1(0)} z^{k} z^{-n^{2}} dz$ for $n=1,2,...$.

Comment: First off, thank you. Then $\int z ^{k-n^2}dz$ should be equal to zero for every $k$ except $k=n^2-1$, and $\int \frac 1 z dz=2\pi i$. (The integrals are both over $C_1(0)$). Am i right?

Comment: @Dorian Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

Take $r>\frac12$. Then, is $\lvert z\rvert\geqslant r$,$$\bigl\lvert(2z)^{-n^2}\bigr\rvert=\frac1{\lvert2z\rvert^{n^2}}\leqslant\frac1{(2r)^{n^2}}.$$Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2r)^{n^2}}$ converges, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2z)^{-n^2}$ converges uniformly on $\bigl\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\lvert z\rvert\geqslant r\bigr\}$ and therefore the sum of your series is a holomorphic function on that region. SInce this occurs for each $r>\frac12$, your function is holomorphic.